# knockoutjs afterRender function in foreach binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to specify an entrance effect on elements being inserted using a knockoutjs foreach binding. Very simple setup:

```
myViewModel.myObservableArray.push({enter:function() { ... });
```

and in the markup:

```
foreach:{data:myObservableArray, afterRender:enter}
```

seems like it should work... right? But it doesn't find the enter function on the item. What I've found does work is:

```
myViewModel.enter = function(something, item) { item.enter(); };

foreach:{data:myObservableArray, afterRender:$root.enter}
```

adding an enter function to the root view model and binding `afterRender` to $root.enter. Enter is then passed the item as its second param so can in turn call the item's enter function, but it feels like a hack.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

To clarify I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicholasstephan/tTcw6/1/).

What this does is very simple, and is covered in more depth in the [animated transitions example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html). It's running a function in the root view model for each dom element that's inserted using the foreach binding.

So the question is: what if I want item specific afterRender, afterAdd or beforeRemove functions? I could see this being useful. Especially if using the template binding to dynamically select a template ([note 4](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_4_dynamically_choosing_which_template_is_used)). Is there a clean way of doing this? Right now I've got an `enter` function in the view model's root that simply calls the `enter` function on the item, but like I said above this feels like a hack.

Answer (score 6):

underscore debounce (_.debounce) is a great solution in such case.

template

```
data-bind=" template: {foreach:myObservableArray, afterRender: runWhenAllRenderDone }
```

debounce function will be executed if afterRender is not fired in last 100 milisecond.

```
var runWhenAllRenderDone = _.debounce(myFunction, 100);

function myFunction(){
    //do some task but do it for once only
}
```

is't it awesome?

Comment: That should be Underscore debounce, not Backbone.

Comment: +1 In my case, I cannot use 'afterRender' to be sure the engin of knockout have finished rendering html because I encapsulated the logic  of the function that change items in the observableArray; code is not accessible from the html. I know that is not elegant but I also use a timeout of x milliseconds before calling another function that is adding css to the new elements nodes. In fact, I just set a timeout of 1 milliseconds and after refreshing my page dozens of times, I don't see any case when my html is not refreshed correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Nope, this is the way [it was designed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_3_using_afterrender_afteradd_and_beforeremove).

From the [Documenation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_3_using_afterrender_afteradd_and_beforeremove):

> Note 3: Using “afterRender”, “afterAdd”, and “beforeRemove”
>
> Sometimes you might want to run custom post-processing logic on the DOM elements generated by your templates. For example, if you’re using a JavaScript widgets library such as jQuery UI, you might want to intercept your templates’ output so that you can run jQuery UI commands on it to transform some of the rendered elements into date pickers, sliders, or anything else.
>
> Generally, the best way to perform such post-processing on DOM elements is to write a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), but if you really just want to access the raw DOM elements emitted by a template, you can use afterRender.
>
> Pass a function reference (either a function literal, or give **the name of a function on your view model**), and Knockout will invoke it immediately after rendering or re-rendering your template.

(Emphasis mine)

---

As it says, a custom binding is another way to do it, and may be better depending on what that `enter()` function does.

Comment: Copying and pasting the documentation and answering the question aren't always the same thing. I'd already read the docs. Though I know that isn't always the case on this forum, so I've removed the downvote. That was just frustration talking...

Comment: @nicholas Sorry it frustrated you, I wasn't trying to brush your question off. I tried to do more than paste the documentation, but the explanation beyond that was pretty simple. You seemed to be asking why it was behaving that way, and the answer is: because it was designed to.

Comment: Yeah, in a rush I hit the down button before I thought about it. You're right, of course. I've edited the question to be more clear. If what I'm trying to do (have a custom, item specific, afterAdd function) isn't what knockout does by default, then the question becomes: how do I make it do what I want? Is there a trick I'm not seeing? Or a piece of code floating around out there I could use? I don't really want to waste a day rebuilding the foreach binding if someone has already done the work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Found another workaround without `timeout`, this technique is based on virtual element `<!-- ko if: $parent.afterRender($index()) --><!-- /ko -->`

```
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    // Editable data
    this.seats = ko.observableArray([
        { name: "Steve", meal: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 343},
        { name: "Steve", meal: "Premium (lobster)", price: 10},
        { name: "Steve", meal: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290}
    ]);

    this.afterRender = (i) => {
       // checking element rendered is last
       if (i === this.seats().length - 1) { 
           console.log('rendered');
           // our after rendered logic goes here...
       }
    };
}
```

And it's template is

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: meal"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: price"></td>
    </tr>    
    <!-- ko if: $parent.afterRender($index()) --><!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

This extra logic `i === this.seats().length - 1`, will check last row is rendered.. then we can execute our afterRender logic inside.